# Indeterminate Checkboxes with Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to implement indeterminate checkboxes with Alpine.js

You can select all checkboxes, but when you try to uncheck some checkbox, there all checkboxes are unchecked.

Take a look: https://codepen.io/nuno360/pen/gOwXpXP

```
<table x-data="{ allChecked: [] }"
    x-init="
        $watch('allChecked', value => {
            if (value.length === 0) {
                $refs.all.indeterminate = false;
                $refs.all.checked = false
            } else if (value.length == all.length) {
                $refs.all.indeterminate = false;
                $refs.all.checked = true
            } else {
                $refs.all.indeterminate = true
            }
        })
    " class="bg-white min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="h-14 leading-none" width="60"><input id="all" x-ref="all" @change="allChecked = $event.target.checked ? all : []; console.log(allChecked)" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox border-gray-300 h-5 w-5 cursor-pointer rounded"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="h-14 text-left text-xs text-gray-800 uppercase">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="h-14 relative px-6"><span class="sr-only">Editar</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
        <tr class="hover:bg-gray-100">
            <td class="h-14 leading-none text-center" width="60">
                <input name="delete[]" x-model="allChecked" value="1" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox border-gray-300 h-5 w-5 cursor-pointer rounded">
            </td>
            <td class="py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                Regional Paradigm Technician
            </td>
            <td class="px-5 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                <a href="#" class="text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-900">Editar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hover:bg-gray-100">
            <td class="h-14 leading-none text-center" width="60">
                <input name="delete[]" x-model="allChecked" value="2" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox border-gray-300 h-5 w-5 cursor-pointer rounded">
            </td>
            <td class="py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                Inter Paradigm
            </td>
            <td class="px-5 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                <a href="#" class="text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-900">Editar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for not being able to deselect a single option is because `all` in the below line gives the ref which is a dom element for the `watch` function.

```html
<input id="all" x-ref="all" @change="allChecked = $event.target.checked ? all : []; console.log(allChecked)" type="checkbox" class="...">
```

We need to set the `allChecked` array to `['1','2']` if the `all` checkbox is checked  So to solve this issue,

```html
<input id="all" x-ref="all" @change="allChecked = $event.target.checked ? ['1','2'] : []; console.log(allChecked)" type="checkbox" class="...">
```

**Update**

To automatically pass the values, we can use a function that collects all values of a checkbox to an array as below.

```html
<table x-data="{ allChecked: [], getValues(){
 var array = []
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[x-model=allChecked]')

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  array.push(checkboxes[i].value)
}
return array;
               } }" x-init="..." >
```

And use the `getValues` function instead of hardcoding as below.

```html
<input id="all" x-ref="all" @change="allChecked = $event.target.checked ? getValues() : []; console.log(allChecked)" type="checkbox" class="...">
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I do it dynamic? Without passing manually the items?

Comment: yes, you can have it as a data prop where all the values of the checkboxes. or target the checkboxes with a data-prop or a class and collect the values to an array.

Comment: @NAG Please see the update on the answer to automatically get the checkbox values.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Do you can help me to put the related checkbox as indeterminate when some children are checked? Please check: https://codepen.io/nuno360/pen/YzpLyqw Thanks!

Comment: I think the demo you have works fine. What's wrong with it?. can you explain a scenario where it fails?

Comment: If you click on Argentina, on the right button "23 regions", you will see that you have 2 options checked, but the Argentina checkbox is not indeterminate.